# Change view with ajax or jquery in mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to send data and change view. I put breakpoint, second view worked but not show to me. I don't want to use `Html.BeginForm` because I am working with hmtl and javacript.

```
public ActionResult Second(int id)
{
    List<Properties> users = GetData(id);
    return View(users);
}

$('select').on('change', function (e) {
    //var id = $(this).find(":selected").val()
    var id = this.selectedIndex;
    var targetUrl = '/Home/Second/' + id.toString();
    $(this).load(targetUrl);
});
```

Comment: _I dont wanna use `@Html.BeginForm()`_? - that makes no sense (that method just generate html). And `$(this).load(targetUrl);` makes no sense - `$(this)` is the `<select>` - how would you expect to load a view in your `<select>` (and BTW, `.load()` **is** ajax!) . And what is `location` in the second method

Comment: And you do realize that the while point of ajax is to stay in the same page (ajax calls cannot redirect to another view)

Comment: thx @StephenMuecke

Comment: @DenizOzogul if you figured it out than either delete your question or post your own answer.

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski I did. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Fix that

```
$('select').on('change', function (e) {
    var id = this.selectedIndex;
    var targetUrl = '/Home/Second/' + id.toString();
    location.href = targetUrl;
});
```